# Android:Statistics Number of installed app

Tags: android

I want to get statistics such as the number of the installed apps and the number of active installs in a day.
How can I get the unique information of each mobile device?

When I have this unique information I can save it in MySql db with php and show statistics.

---

thanks all,I mean unique information Like UUID of Android phone

Comment: Here are the docs: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?hl=en

Comment: Do you want this information for your app? For example, number of people that downloaded / used / uninstalled YOUR app?

Comment: @OrhanC1 yes for my app

Comment: @sadegh Ok. I've posted an answer for you.

Comment: Do each mobile device have unique id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the data you're looking for is provided by the Google Play service. Once you upload your APK, you'll start getting statistics on your app.

If you need more granular data, look into 'Flurry'. It's free, easy to set up, and quite powerful.

Comment: Flurry does not allow the use of its services in your country. If you have any questions or believe you may have received this message in error, please contact us at legal@flurry.com.  :(

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that! I'm afraid that Flurry is the only service I've used but you can check out this link for more info http://www.google.com.tr/analytics/mobile/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this framework to track app statistics across various platforms:

http://www.distimo.com/